# how can i learn javascript coding patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

First what i mean by patterns.. Basically in Js there are multiple ways to do something but some ways of doing things offer greater benefits in terms of portability, performance, modularity, and extension. One of the patterns i like most are of jquery.

But when writing my own code i feel urge to just keep on writing function after function...and i don't want to create an object just for the sake of organization. There should be a reason like reusability for object to be created.

I want to learn patterns that make more use of closures, prototype, objects and chaining. So i can write better code.

I know keeping code simple is best but when things are wide spread keeping code less intrusive and reusable is maybe more important.

Comment: please don't hesitate to add tips and links to resources even after answer has been selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this out:
http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

This book was also pretty useful:
JavaScript Patterns
Build Better Applications with Coding and Design Patterns
By Stoyan Stefanov
Publisher: O'Reilly Media

This book really helped me getting started. Apart from that I suggest googling up, reading various articles,blogs, whatever you think is useful.

Comment: Great link - you beat me to it! Also important: learning general best-practices. Stoyan Stefanov wrote a fantastic book that was invaluable, and still is, for me: [JavaScript Patterns](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Patterns-Stoyan-Stefanov/dp/0596806752). It covers a lot of what's in the link (above), as well as other best-practices and concepts for code reuse.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother trying to learn every single aspect of JavaScript before you actually need it.

If you suddenly find yourself passing masses of variables to your functions then you might find it easier to use objects, but objects are generally only useful if the data they encapsulate is related in some way. That means since you are aware of objects then as soon as the need arises for them in your code, you'll realise that's the time to use them.

Since objects properties and methods are so easily added to variables in JavaScript it's probably overkill to write out functions to construct objects/override variable prototypes etc.

As a very broad generalization, in languages such as Perl and php, for most programs of less than 1000 lines objects are overkill.

Play it by ear and take the easy way out every time.

Answer (score 1):

I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook) Google talk a few weeks ago and was inspired to read Crockford's entire book, "JavaScript: The Good Parts".  Watch the talk and I think you'll find it's exactly what you're looking for, full of best practices for using closures & prototype.  It's a little old and just covers core JavaScript, nothing about JQuery, ect. but if that's what you're looking for, this is your book.

[http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)